# Starting Typesafe Play Framework using HTTPS/SSL

Tags: ssl, https, playframework, configuration, keystore

I'm having trouble getting our system up and running using HTTPS.

I have created a keyfile from our wildcard certificate and placed the keyfile in our `./conf` directory:

```
473 zbeckman:glimpulse-server$ ll conf
total 72
drwxr-xr-x 9 zbeckman staff 306 Sep 7 09:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 zbeckman staff 748 Sep 7 09:32 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zbeckman staff 1213 Sep 7 09:26 application.conf*
-rw-r--r-- 1 zbeckman staff 1374 Sep 7 08:49 glimpulse.keystore
-rw-r--r-- 1 zbeckman staff 1439 Aug 9 15:58 logback.xml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zbeckman staff 5206 Aug 8 15:36 routes*
-rw-r--r-- 1 zbeckman staff 575 Apr 29 18:55 ws.conf
474 zbeckman:glimpulse-server$
```

And I have added the following to our `./conf/application.conf` file, as per instructions in the Play [Configuring HTTPS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ConfiguringHttps) page:

```
play.server.https.keyStore.path = "./conf/glimpulse.keystore"
play.server.https.keyStore.password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

And finally, I'm using `-Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.port=9000` to try and start the server, but it refuses to start.

Here are the results. Note the last line of output:

```
472 zbeckman:glimpulse-server$ ./activator start -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.port=9000
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/zbeckman/Projects/Glimpulse/Server/project/glimpulse-server/project
[info] Set current project to Glimpulse (in build file:/Users/zbeckman/Projects/Glimpulse/Server/project/glimpulse-server/)
[warn] The start command is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version of Play.
[warn] To run Play in production mode, run 'stage' instead, and then execute the generated start script in target/universal/stage/bin.
[warn] To test your application using production mode, run 'testProd' instead.
[info] Wrote /Users/zbeckman/Projects/Glimpulse/Server/project/glimpulse-server/target/scala-2.11/glimpulse_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)

Must provide either an HTTP or HTTPS port
473 zbeckman:glimpulse-server$
```

As far as the keystore goes, I used the Java `keytool` to generate the store, based on our wildcard domain certificate:

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore glimpulse.keystore -trustcacerts -file star_glimpulse_com.crt
```

That seemed to go just fine, and the keystore was generated without any errors or warnings.

Comment: Have you made any progress yet? I keep hitting a similar brick wall when it comes to running Play with HTTPS. If anyone has the answer they do not appear to be sharing it. I did run across a demo once that actually worked but is seems like there is some voodoo with how the cert is created that I have not decoded enough yet to apply to a project that was not started from the demo/sample.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to run it like this:

`./activator "start -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.port=9000"`

The quotes may be required to make sure the parameters get passed to the start command the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your application.conf:

```
https {
  # The HTTPS port of the server.
  port = 9001
}
```

and your app will listen on port 9001